# how to delete a partial string from column 2 in a file

Tags: text-processing

Input :

```
4857544398A7CB9C(HWTC98A7CB9C); AHH-ABN-19-2-59-0720000000-amir3456; 129
```

Desired output:

```
4857544398A7CB9C(HWTC98A7CB9C),amirzain,129
```

I want to delete every thing before the last hyphen (`-`) in column 2 by using `sed` or any command.

Comment: Is that *dangling* capital A at the beginning of `Aamirzain` an accident?  Also, your description doesn't mention changing `;` to `,`, but the desired output does ...

Comment: How do you define a column?

Comment: How is `amirzain` derived from your input?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want what your question asks for: "I want to delete every thing before the last hyphen (-) in column 2", you can use this:

```
$ awk '{sub(/.*-/,"",$2)}1' file
4857544398A7CB9C(HWTC98A7CB9C); amirzain; 129
```

If you instead want the output you show, which means removing everything before the last hyphen in column 2, changing `amirzain` to `Amirzain` and changing the semicolons to colons, you can use this instead:

```
$ perl -lne '@F=split(/; /); $F[1] =~s/^.+-(.)/\U$1/; print join ",",@F' file
4857544398A7CB9C(HWTC98A7CB9C),Amirzain,129
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **awk** :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";";OFS=","}{n=split($2, seq, "-");$2=seq[n];print}' <file>
```

OUTPUT :

```
4857544398A7CB9C(HWTC98A7CB9C),amirzain, 129
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the capital `A` in the second column is an accident, and that the `,` instead of `;` in the output is intentional:

```
echo '4857544398A7CB9C(HWTC98A7CB9C); AHH-ABN-19-2-59-0720000000-amirzain; 129'|sed -r 's/^([^;]+); .*-([^;]+); (.*)/\1,\2,\3/' 
4857544398A7CB9C(HWTC98A7CB9C),amirzain,129
```

If you want to use that on an entire file, add a `i` to the flags for sed:

```
sed -ri 's/^([^;]+); .*-([^;]+); (.*)/\1,\2,\3/' file
```

Comment: @user446276 - are you sure you're using Linux?

Comment: What version of `sed` is this?!  `-r` has been valid in GNU sed for at least a decade ...

Comment: What does `sed --version` say?